WKWebView with Gesture Recognizer becomes unresponsible when using Apple Pencil
I have a SwiftUI ContentView that includes a WKWebView, and I've added a custom UIGestureRecognizer to the WKWebView. Here's a simplified version of my code:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        WebView(urlString: "http://localhost")
    }
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let urlString: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        
        let recognizer = BaseGesture()
        
        webView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
        
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            uiView.load(request)
        }
    }
}

class BaseGesture: UIGestureRecognizer {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        print(touches)
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        print(touches)
    }
        
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        print(touches)
    }
    
    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        print(touches)
    }
}

The WebView contains a simple React app.
function App() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{count}</p>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>hello world</button>
        </div>
    );
}

When using touch gestures with fingers, the recognizer works perfectly. However, when using an Apple Pencil, the WebView becomes unresponsive. Simply tapping with the Apple Pencil works, but when moving the pencil across the screen, the page becomes unresponsive after lifting up the pencil.
The react app has the following style applied to prevent over scrolling:
html {
  overscroll-behavior: none;
}

When using the following instead of overscroll-behavior the issues persists:
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

Occasionally, the terminal prints the fault:
Touch event gesture recognizer failed to reset after ending gesture deferral: ( "<WKDeferringGestureRecognizer: 0x135e0e320 (Deferrer for touch start (immediate reset)); baseClass = UIGestureRecognizer; state = Ended; view = <WKContentView: 0x13980b200>>"

I can't consistently reproduce the error, and I'm unsure what causes it.
Any help or insights would be appreciated. Thank you!

// create local variable of UIPencilInteraction
var applePencil: UIPencilInteraction!
var tapGuesture: UITapGestureRecognizer!

// initize this on uiview and add applePencil delegate
applePencil = UIPencilInteraction()
applePencil.delegate = self
view.addInteraction(applePencil)

// now add tap guesture on your webview
yourwebview.addGuestureRecorgnizer(tapGuesture)
yourwebview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

//then add tapguresture on yourbview.
 @objc func tapGuesture(_ guesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let touchEvent = guesture.location(in: webView) // get touchPoint on 
        
        // if you want to trigger touch event using apple pencil then you need to check  forceTouchCapability
        if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available && guesture.force > 0 {
            // it means this is pencil event
            yourwebview.evaluateJavaScript("document.elementFromPoint(\(touchEvent.x), \(touchEvent.y))?.click()")
        }
        else
        {
            // regular touch point
        }
    }
    
    // WKNavigationDelegate methods if needed

// traitCollection is the property of UIView, it defines the set of traits in which view is displayed, the forceTouch Capability is the property which indicates where 3d touch supported ot not. Developer link (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection/1623515-forcetouchcapability)
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

please check this answer and let me know if your issue is resolved
